# How do I add 'exists:' to a rule?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to run a Gitlab pipeline stage after pushing a commit on the 'master' branch and a directory named 'tests' exists in the project root. Here is the relevant snippet from  .gitlab-ci.yaml that defines the stage and its rules:

```
    stage: test
    image: python:3.10.3-bullseye
    rules:
        -   if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
            exists:
                - tests
    before_script: *setup-python
    script:
        - pip install -e .[dev]
        - pytest tests/
```

However, after a commit on the master branch, it remains disabled. I'm a bit fuzzy on the syntax, despite reading the docs carefully. Does anyone know how to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: try `- tests/**/*`

Answer (score 1):

As in https://docs.gitlab.com/14.10/ee/ci/yaml/#rules,

> Rules are evaluated when the pipeline is created, and evaluated in
> order until the first match. When a match is found, the job is either
> included or excluded from the pipeline, depending on the
> configuration.

Try,

```
stage: test
image: python:3.10.3-bullseye
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"
    when: never
  - exists:
    - tests/**/*.py
before_script: *setup-python
script:
  - pip install -e .[dev]
  - pytest tests/
```